# Sort by time, showing only where unique

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `myTable` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `time` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `item` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `time` (`time`),
  KEY `item` (`item`),
  KEY `price` (`price`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;


INSERT INTO `myTable` (`ID`, `time`, `item`, `price`) VALUES
(1, 100, 'cat', 10),
(2, 101, 'cat', 10),
(3, 102, 'cat', 9),
(4, 103, 'cat', 11),
(5, 104, 'cat', 10),
(6, 105, 'cat', 10),
(7, 106, 'cat', 11);
```

I'm trying to figure out a query that would return the following:

```
time   item   price
----   ----   -----
100    cat    10
102    cat    9
103    cat    11
104    cat    10
106    cat    11
```

It's ordered by time, and shows only rows where the price is different to the price before it (***Edit:*** **According to time**).

**EDIT:**

Maybe I made the original problem too simple, what if it was more complex with data like this:

```
INSERT INTO `myTable` (`ID`, `time`, `item`, `price`) VALUES
(1111, 100, 'cat', 10),
(21, 105, 'cat', 10),
(31, 108, 'cat', 9),
(411, 109, 'cat', 11),
(512, 110, 'cat', 10),
(61, 114, 'cat', 10),
(72, 120, 'cat', 11),
(8, 100, 'dog', 20),
(93, 102, 'dog', 20),
(104, 108, 'dog', 29),
(111, 109, 'dog', 31),
(122, 155, 'dog', 20),
(13, 165, 'dog', 20),
(1445, 172, 'dog', 31);
```

In the above, the ID column is all messed up, perhaps there are other records in between. Also the time no longer increments by 1 and I've thrown a dog into the mix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you need is this:

```
select curr.time  ,
       curr.item  ,
       curr.price 
from myTable curr
join myTable prev on prev.time = ( select max(time)
                                   from myTable p
                                   where p.time < curr.time
                                 )
where curr.price != prev.price
order by t.time
```

It takes advantage of the fact that time is an alternate key for the table. We take all the rows from `myTable` (let's call it *current*) such that its price is different than that of the previous row based on the the value of the alternate key *time* (lets call this set *previous*).

To do this, we need a [*correlated subquery*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) that identifies the highest value of `time` less than or equal to the value of of `time` for the current row. So...we wind up referencing `myTable` thrice:

- First, for the set of 'current' rows,
- Second, for the set of 'previous' rows'
- Third, to identify the 'previous' row based on the data in the 'current' row.

Easy!

Answer (score 2):

this query will get for each row, the price of the before id, and make a comparison, showing it if it's different

```
select time, item, price
from mytable T1
where price != (select price from mytable where id < t1.id order by id desc limit 1) or T1.id = 1
```

Comment: @mellamokb: only if the ID values are always contiguous and always inserted in ascending order by time. Neither of those conditions is a given.

Comment: In the data example yes, at least

Comment: Could change the subquery to `select price from mytable where time < t1.time order by time desc limit 1` in order to resolve @NicholasCarey's (valid) concerns.

Comment: @ElVieejo: Thanks for your help, I've just edited the question to reflect what Nicholas Carey's point as well as some others.